# Check Winner Naughts and Crosses game - Lua/Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am quite new to the Lua language and am trying to create a simple Tic Tac Toe game. I am having difficulties figuring out how to check the winner. I have tried if-then statements but I think I am using them wrong. Not sure what the best way to check the winner is so any suggestions or assistance is greatly appreciated.

The code is -

```
local composer = require( "composer" )

local scene = composer.newScene()

d = display
w20 = d.contentWidth * .2
h20 = d.contentHeight * .2
w40 = d.contentWidth * .4
h40 = d.contentHeight * .4
w60 = d.contentWidth * .6
h60 = d.contentHeight * .6
w80 = d.contentWidth * .8
h80 = d.contentHeight * .8

----DRAW LINES FOR BOARD
local lline = d.newLine(w40,h20,w40,h80 )
lline.strokeWidth = 5

local rline = d.newLine(w60,h20,w60,h80 )
rline.strokeWidth = 5

local bline = d.newLine(w20,h40,w80,h40 )
bline.strokeWidth = 5

local tline = d.newLine(w20,h60,w80,h60 )
tline.strokeWidth = 5


--PLACE BOARD COMPARTMENT DIMENSIONS IN TABLE
board ={
{"tl",1,w20,h40,w40,h20,0},
{"tm",2,w40,h40,w60,h20,0},
{"tr",3,w60,h40,w80,h20,0},
{"ml",4,w20,h60,w40,h40,0},
{"mm",5,w40,h60,w60,h40,0},
{"mr",6,w60,h60,w80,h40,0},
{"bl",7,w20,h80,w40,h60,0},
{"bm",8,w40,h80,w60,h60,0},
{"br",9,w60,h80,w80,h60,0}
}
--

local EMPTY, X, O = 0, 1, 2
local whichTurn = 0



--FILL COMPARTMENT W/ COLOUR WHEN TOUCHED
local function fill(event)
if (event.phase == "ended") then
    for t = 1,9 do
        if event.x > board[t][3] and event.x < board[t][5] then
            if event.y < board[t][4] and event.y > board[t][6] then 
             if board[t][7] == EMPTY then
              if whichTurn == 1 then
                whichTurn = 2
              else
                whichTurn = 1
              end
                board[t][7] = whichTurn
                 if board[t][7] == 1 then
           local xText = display.newText("X", board[t][3], board[t][4], "Arial", 80)
           xText.anchorX = 0
           xText.anchorY = 100
                 elseif board[t][7] == 2 then 
                   local oText = display.newText("O", board[t][3], board[t][4], "Arial", 80)
                   oText.anchorX = 0
                   oText.anchorY = 100
                 end
             end
          end
        end
    end
end


local function checkWinner()
  for i = 1,9 do
    if board[i][2] == 1 and board[i][7] == 1 then
      boxOne = "x"
    end
    if board[i][2] == 2 and board[i][7] == 1 then
      boxTwo = "x"
    end
    if board[i][2] == 3 and board[i][7] == 1 then
      boxThree = "x"
    end
    if boxOne == "x" and boxTwo == "x" and boxThree == "x" then
      display.newText("Winner", 10, 100, "Arial", 200)
    end
  end
end



end

Runtime:addEventListener ("touch", fill)



return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

```
local All_Lines = {{1,5,9}, {3,5,7}, {1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {3,6,9}}

local function checkWinner()
   for _, Line in ipairs(All_Lines) do
      local values = 0
      for _, idx in ipairs(Line) do
         values = values * 10 + board[idx][7]
      end
      if values == 111 then
         display.newText("Winner", 10, 100, "Arial", 200)
         return
      elseif values == 222 then
         display.newText("Loser", 10, 100, "Arial", 200)
         return
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Please provide context to your answer. Just giving the code doesn't help the OP in the long run :)

Comment: @RoelStrolenberg - My code should be considered in the context of OP's code (my code is actually a function `checkWinner` which depends on the objects defined in the OP's code).  I agree that my code without the context does not have any value.

Comment: Hi @EgorSkriptunoff thank you for the reply. I have included it in the code and must not be doing something right as it doesn't seem to be working. It just doesn't seem to run that function at all. Is there something I am supposed to include to make call a function as I have not been able to find anything that tells me how?

Comment: @Katie - You should include invocation of this function into some event handler.